# create a word document in asp.net based on a word template

Tags: asp.net, word-template

I need to create a word document in asp.net based on a word template.does any one have a good article which i can follow. 
I have gone through several articles.still haven't got a clear idea to begin with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try look here:

http://docx.codeplex.com/

here an example with template:

http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2009/08/docx-v1007-released.html